# SpringBoot & Thymeleaf multiple select dropdown not showing selected when editing

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, jquery-select2, multipleselection

My project uses Java 8, Springboot 2 and Thymeleaf 3. I want to add a multiple select drop down to my form. I've tried it a few different ways, like trying to use Select2, and trying to just manually do it with Thymeleaf & Springboot.... I eventually got the select2 to work and make it a drop down view. I can get the functionality of it to work but can't get the selection to show up on the editable view. All options get to the SQL database, and if you only have one choice it will show on the edit page, but if more than one option is selected, it wont show anything on the edit broker page.

If I change to th:name instead of th:field, I can see the selected options, but now I can not save any options as well...

I am not getting any errors so I am not sure why this isn't working. Any idea what I need to do to get the edit view to show all options selected? Is it some sort of binding issue?

```html
 <select  id="brokerTargetIndustries"  th:field="*{brokerTargetIndustries}" multiple="multiple" class="text-left form-control" >
        <option value="Social Service WC" th:selected="${broker!=null and broker!=null and broker.targetIndustries!=null and #strings.contains(broker.targetIndustries,'Social Service WC')}">Social Service WC</option>
        <option value="Propane Fuel Dealers" selected="${broker!=null and broker.targetIndustries!=null and #strings.contains(broker.targetIndustries,'Propane Fuel Dealers')}">Propane/Fuel Dealers</option>
        <option value="Building Services PKG" selected="${broker!=null and broker.targetIndustries!=null and #strings.contains(broker.targetIndustries,'Building Services PKG')}">Building Services PKG</option>
        <option value="Contractor WC" selected="${broker!=null and broker.targetIndustries!=null and #strings.contains(broker.targetIndustries,'Contractor WC')}">Contractor WC</option>
</select>
```

Here is the controller for edit:

```html
    @RequestMapping(value="/edit/{id}")
    public String editBroker(Model model,@PathVariable("id") Long id, Broker broker){
        Broker existing = brokerRepository.findById(id).get();
        model.addAttribute("broker",existing);
        return "brokerProfile";
    }
```